# Revert a display name change within 24 hours

Tags: feature-request, display-names

Today I changed my username on Stack Overflow to something slightly obnoxious (Okay, really really obnoxious) to match some of the April Fools day theming going on with some other members. Unfortunately, I did not realize at the time that changing your display name is not revertible. I'm stuck with this obnoxious name for the next month because I wanted to get in on the April Fools day joke.

Could we have the ability to revert a name change within 24 hours?

Comment: I'm so glad I wasn't the only idiot to find this out the hard way. :-D

Comment: Also, see my feature request:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/add-warning-when-changing-display-name

Comment: Sorry about the dupe guys. I saw that I was stuck and kind of panic'd.  Seems every question I ever send to meta is a dupe :(

Comment: This question appears to request something different in the title from in the body. Since the titular request is unique and not a duplicate, I've edited the body to no longer make the duplicate request and just make the titular feature request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No problem.

Flag one of your posts for moderator attention, and indicate you'd like your name changed back to "x" -- we'll get it done!

Comment: *Bill bows down to the creator...* Thank you :)