# Not allowing to change display-name

Tags: feature-request, display-names

I have updated my profile on SO by changing my Display Name, and today i have tried again to change my Display Name, but it showing the following error message:

[image]

What it make sense ?? that error message is displaying after the user tried to change their name, (this is the case same as user jump into the well, after that you are saving their life and giving alert).

**Instead, you should show the alert message while the user is changing their Display Name or updating profile.**

Comment: It might be an idea to disable the input altogether when the display name can't be changed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45208/possible-feature-request-revert-a-display-name-change-within-24-hours and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58083/can-i-get-a-one-time-break-on-the-name-change-every-thirty-days-rule

Comment: +1 for suggesting a warning **PRIOR** to changing display names. Rubbish design, and still no one does anything about it although it is a known problem.