# Lower the time when it is allowed to change the display name

Tags: feature-request, display-names

Few days ago I changed my display name. I put my full name and last name, but now I think it is too long.

It would be great if you would lower the time for how long it is disallowed to change the display name. If not that, then at least to put some time to revert the changes or to change it to something else.

Comment: -1 because I disagree. I think one should be careful in choosing ones identity, and it can be overly disruptive to a "community" in general when people can too easily do so.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I agree, but in that case there should be some kind of warning about very long display names. Also, it is already easy to change the display name. You just have to wait

Comment: True; but the wait at least makes it difficult for someone to constantly "disguise" themselves. In that way, it is "difficult". Changed my mind and removed the -1 vote, btw, though; I don't  feel as strongly as I did two minutes ago!

Comment: You do have *a little* time to change it to something else. I can't remember for sure, but I think it's something like five minutes.

Comment: @JeremyBanks 5 minutes is nothing. I realized my display name is too long, after someone replied to my comment.

Comment: Related: [Can we restrict the ability of users to keep changing their names?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names), [Revert a display name change within 24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45208/possible-feature-request-revert-a-display-name-change-within-24-hours), [Add Warning when Changing Display Name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/add-warning-when-changing-display-name)

Comment: (@Jeremy, it's [15 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names/38180#38180), unless things have changed since February 2010.)

Comment: @Arjan You're right. I'm testing it right now, and I'm still able to edit it after 12 minutes (edit: I'm still able to change it after 17, so apparently it locks after being unchanged for 15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a work around.

Change your name on another of your linked sites and then copy *that* profile information to all other sites.

So if you have a Super User account as well change the name there then go to the Accounts tab on Super User and click the "Copy Super User profile to all Stack Exchange accounts" button.

Obviously if you want different names on different sites this won't work and will cause you more work if you have different e-mail addresses and/or profiles on different sites as these will get overwritten too.