# Can I get a one-time break on the name-change-every-thirty-days rule?

Tags: feature-request, display-names, rate-limiting

I had no idea -- perhaps there was no warning, or perhaps I didn't read it -- that if I changed my name it would be stuck for 30 days. I just want to go back to the name I've been using for months. Can I get a one-time pass?

Comment: A warning about the 30 day rule would be nice.

Comment: You can copy your profile from SO over this one again (or the other way around - whichever is the right one). That doesn't get counted as a name change (or at least it *didn't* - maybe that has changed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just [copy your profile from your other accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54986/name-change-limiting-can-be-broken/55023#55023). This bypasses the restriction, giving you up to 3 shots between the 4 sites in the trilogy per 30 day period. Sure, you might have to update other parts of your profile, but those aren't rate-limited. Just don't be abusive of this feature.

That said, a warning would indeed be useful.

Comment: That is great. Now if I could just find that icon I used on my hard drive :) Thank you!

Comment: @Yar What icon on your harddrive? Changing your name doesn't affect your gravatar.

Comment: @George But copying his profile overwrote his email address, which does affect the Gravatar.

Comment: He shouldn't need to find an icon on his hard drive for that though

Comment: @Michael @Grace @George: it's true, it was in my gravatar account. Now if there was a meta.gravatar.com I would have someplace to complain :)