# Does account creation count as a screen name change WRT the 30-day rule?

Tags: discussion, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get a one-time break on the name-change-every-thirty-days rule?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58083/can-i-get-a-one-time-break-on-the-name-change-every-thirty-days-rule)

Here's why I'm asking.

I visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860759/c-finding-largest-number-in-binary-tree) a few times, and in between the time the question was posted (the user is new) and when I visited again I'm pretty sure the screen name changed from "Amanda" to "Becca."

I'm guessing users can change their screen names (once) immediately after creating their accounts?

In this particular case, it seems odd to change the name like this, *unless*:

- The person's real name is Amanda, and
- That question wasn't a practice exam question, but one from the real exam she was taking.

**I'm not saying that this user was actually cheating, because I don't know,** but given that the two questions were homework questions, the thought crossed my mind.

Just looking for some discussion to see if a feature request is in order.

Thanks!

Comment: Those two questions are really similar, yet they got wildly different receptions from the community. Odd.

Comment: It's quite possible that "Amanda" and "Becca" were two accounts that were merged.

Comment: @Charles:  Hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I read Jeff saying somewhere that new accounts can change name as often as they want.

Comment: Like this?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58083/can-i-get-a-one-time-break-on-the-name-change-every-thirty-days-rule