# Unable to change display name

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I tried to change my display name just moments ago, and I got the error:

> Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change
>   again on Apr 11 at 3:54

I have never changed my account display name. Looking back, I did start an account on the UX StackExchange 3 days ago (with no activity so far), which could be what is triggering the message. If that's the case - is this by design? If it is, I think that the error message should be more clear. If not, any idea what the problem is?

Comment: The timeline of your UX account creation 3 days ago *does* seem to line up with the date given in the error message, exactly 30 days from March 11th.

Comment: I can't say whether this is by design or not, but a possible workaround is given here: [Can I get a one-time break on the name-change-every-thirty-days rule?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58083/can-i-get-a-one-time-break-on-the-name-change-every-thirty-days-rule)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this issue up. I am unable to reproduce it in the current build of our network sites. If it remains an issue please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Join a new community and choose the option to update all accounts.

Comment: Indeed, as already mentioned in the duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58083/can-i-get-a-one-time-break-on-the-name-change-every-thirty-days-rule.