# Profile sync allows subverting the limit on display name changes

Tags: bug, profile-page, display-names, profile-sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Name Change Limiting can be Broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54986/name-change-limiting-can-be-broken)

I played around with display names on SO testing out what input is really allowed. When I decided to change the name back later I noticed that I cannot, I am rather expected to wait until end of September ([30 days waiting period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names)). Now the funny thing is that my MSO profile still had the old name and even allowed me to change it. Makes sense so far, accounts on all the Stack Exchange sites are independent of each other.

Now I would expect some mechanism to prevent me from syncing the display name from MSO to SO. But it seems that there is none, I synced the profiles and had my old display name back on SO. Only remaining side-effect: I still cannot change the name on SO. But there are plenty of other sites available should I feel the need to do this before end of September.

Not sure whether this is worth fixing but it certainly is a logic flaw.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Name Change Limiting can be Broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54986).

Comment: @Hendrik: Similar but not quite the same - my approach is simpler. Still, given that the other report didn't receive any attention in a year I would go with "it's a feature".

Comment: Ah, OK, you're doing it with syncing, the other one is about associating accounts - right?

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes - might be the same code involved, but I cannot be certain about it.