# Possible to bypass display name change restrictions

Tags: bug, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Name Change Limiting can be Broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54986/name-change-limiting-can-be-broken)

On Stack Exchange sites, you only allowed to change your display name every 30 days. Attempting to change the display name inside of this time restriction will result in an error.

Say that I've changed my display name on Stack Overflow *only* (by clicking on  **Save Profile** instead of **Save profile and copy to all Stack Exchange sites**) - I won't be able to change it on stackoverflow.com for the next 30 days.

But if I edit my profile on a site still using my old display name, and then click **Save profile and copy to all Stack Exchange sites**, the display name will be updated on Stack Overflow as well.

This is obviously an oversight in the display name process.

Comment: Even though this is a duplicate, nice work figuring it out!