# Why can't I revert my display name?

Tags: feature-request, display-names

I purposely changed my display name, but now I want to change it back to what it was.

I tried to change it back myself, but I got this error message:

> Display name may only be changed once every 30 days

**NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!** Fine, prevent people from changing their name every day, but at least let them change it back!

Also, I think you should warn users before they perform an irreversible action!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Eh, this is more about reverting it than warning.

Comment: There is a [work-around](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54986/name-change-limiting-can-be-broken). Use that and don't make the same mistake twice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Phew, back to normal. But I shouldn't have fallen into the trap in the first place.

Comment: There is a grace period too, btw. The feature request I linked to would help avoid the trap.