# Is it possible for a user to determine which moderator changed their display name?

Tags: support, moderators, display-names, accountability

I recently ran across a site meta discussion with someone accusing a specific moderator of improperly changing their display name while they were suspended. They had a screenshot of their recent names, which was certainly indicative that *someone* had changed it, and there were too many for the [old "change on a different site" trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54986/name-change-limiting-can-be-broken) to work with their limited number of linked accounts, so they didn't do it themselves. (Well, probably didn't. It's not impossible that they added an account on some random site, changed their name there, deleted that account, and repeated that a few more times. Yes, I have a devious mind.)

However, I was a bit skeptical that they had any particular reason to finger *that* moderator, rather than, say, either of the other two on that site, or perhaps a diamond on the other site they had membership on. Is my skepticism warranted, or is there some cunning way to determine who, exactly, was responsible for this, uh, reprehensible act of villainy, or whatever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not. Unless a moderator *told them* he was changing the name, which may have happened; if you decide to take a particularly offensive name, it'll probably get forcibly changed *and* generate a warning.

Otherwise, just ask one of the other moderators to look up the full history. If he's making public accusations, I see no reason not to make that public as well...

Comment: Fair enough. I already pointed out to them that this sort of "calling out The Man" behavior is more than likely to result in a serious backfire.