# 30 days rate limit on display name changing is not enforced

Tags: bug, display-names, rate-limiting

I noticed a user who was able to change their name after only 19 hours (and 2 minutes), somehow breaking the 30 days rare limit that should be imposed on this:

> [image]

The above proves the name change occurred after 19 hours only.

I'm not sure how they did it<sup>1</sup>, but since they choose silly names each times that are impossible to even remember, it's irritating and I consider this abuse.

Can the bug please be fixed so that users can't change their name so often?

[The screen name change rate limit doesn't exist anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300174/the-screen-name-change-rate-limit-doesnt-exist-anymore) was fixed year and half ago, but obviously some loophole was missed.

<sup>1</sup> I think they did it by changing their name on a [site in private beta](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/) and choosing "Copy to all Sites".

Comment: Do they have an account on the [recently started private beta](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/)? IIRC the new site doesn't have the history of your old usernames, so you can always change it and have it apply to the entire network.

Comment: @Glorfindel yes indeed. Will add the info to the question. Thanks!

Comment: It's also possible that they may be using a script to [change their username every 15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315788/users-can-bypass-the-30-day-username-change-limit-by-constantly-changing-name-wi).

Comment: @Sonic, no. It's clearly 19 hours, not 15 minutes. (changing **so often** would lead to flagging and hopefully quick suspension to stop the troll)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Changing to the same username is considered by the software as a "username change" and still allows another change within 15 minutes.

Comment: @Sonic thanks, didn't know it. However, since NormalHuman also mentioned something about private beta.... that's likely the way.

Comment: Perhaps the user in question is drawing attention to themselves for a noble cause? It *could* be, see their avatar. Ahh, they have changed it again. The user is now called Galastel. Perhaps he asked permission to change the previous, ridiculously long, username

Comment: Oops! Different user but the same avatar.

Comment: @Mari no, he is obviously doing it just for fun. No noble cause there, that's for sure.