# What is the reason for the 30 day wait on changing your user name?

Tags: support, users, user-accounts, display-names

I recently combined 2 OpenID accounts, but I no longer want to use one or the user name associated with it. I have about 6 days left on my wait. Why do I have to wait so long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delay is to avoid frequent name changes, which can be very confusing.

If you have a good reason to change, mail team@stackoverflow.com, I'm sure they can help you.

Answer (score 3):

A few users were having fun here on Meta by changing their names regularly. [Hilarity ensued.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518)

[Then a few whiners ruined it for everyone.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names)

Comment: +1 bring back Colonel Cockpounder! And his daugher Susan.

Comment: LMAO! That's a good enough reason for me :)