# How many times does Stack Overflow allow user to edit user display name?

Tags: discussion

I am curious about many times does Stack Overflow allow user to edit user display name? Is there any restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user display name change and discussion surrounding that can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names). I post the rules stated by [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood):

1. only one display name change is allowed every 30 days
2. user accounts less than 2 days old may change their displayname at will
3. there is a 15 minute grace period after each change during which you may change your displayname at will.

But, then changing the display name on any of the another linked sites and then clicking on *Save and Copy Profile to All Stackexchange account* will update the display names in all the linked sites.

Comment: thanks @The New Idiot