# Why is there a time limit for changing the username?

Tags: discussion

Is there a reason a limit is imposed on the number of times you can change your username?

Comment: I just clicked and didn't receive my dollar, I'll let you know once I receive it.

Comment: @PeterJ  profile views == 0 wait for it to become 1 to convert to a dollar :)

Comment: @Arjan That question is asking for a way to limit the username change even more, whereas this is asking about the reasons of why the actual limit exists.

Comment: @clickheretoearnadollar the question explains why they requested the feature, as do the comments under the accepted answer... doesn't that answer your question as to why?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, reading it further I can see that. Can this question be kept? I think that other users searching for the same thing will find it straightford here rather than the other question, because it isn't as direct as this one.

Comment: @clickheretoearnadollar closing as a duplicate doesn't mean the question gets deleted.  It just gets closed as a duplicate and points users to the other question to see the answer.  So it actually helps people with the same question

Comment: @psubsee2003 mmm ok, thank you. Still, has this question to be answered or will it work just as a easy-placeholder to that question --> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names ?

Comment: @clickheretoearnadollar it will be more like a sign post pointing someone in the proper direction.  The banner that you see now above the question will be visible to everyone once this gets closed and there will be a message below this question telling users to find their answer on the other question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Fine, let's close this question to answers then :)