# What are the terms for changing the username?

Tags: support, display-names

> [image]

I see that you can not change your username as you want and when you want. So, are there more terms for changing the username?

Answer (score 10):

The only terms regarding usernames [are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29966/391772):

- You can only change it once every 30 days (after the 5 minute grace period:)
- After every name change, there is 5 mins grace period - you can edit your name as many times as you want within 5 minutes of the first edit
- It can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens, and must start with a letter or digit

Comment: Given the requirements you mention, your display name is rather ironic

Comment: What's the 5 mins grace period?

Comment: Of course it will. But once you change your name,  you can change it again for the next 5 minutes the number of times you like. After this grace period passes, the name is locked for 30 days.

Comment: @nicael Ahhh... sorry - 'grace period' Duh...!