# The screen name change rate limit doesn't exist anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names, rate-limiting

According to Jeff, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180/228134

> - only one display name change is allowed every 30 days
> - there is a 15 minute grace period after each change during which you may change your displayname at will

I recently got a mod message about my name changes and they said that I am gaming the system by using other methods.

Actually I am able to change my name on the same site as much as I want without any limit.

These are my name changes I made in Stack Overflow without getting any system warning.

[image]

So There is no rate limit preventing me from changing my name.

Is this limit lifted or is it a bug? (tested on other sites as well)

Comment: It's a bug, as you've been told ;)

Comment: yes. that's the bug tag is there. oh wait. let me find another title

Comment: Not only that, but the post you referenced is 7 years old. Even if it wasn't a bug, don't you think there is a large possibility things change after 7 years?

Comment: @patricksweeney: Not without it being reflected in a meta post somewhere and mirrored in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, this has been broken since January, after a large refactoring of the user settings saving code.

A check to see if the new display name was different to the old display name was mistakenly changed to see if the new display name was different to the... new display name. Which of course it isn't, which bypassed the time check (because - if the name hasn't changed, why check further?).

This has now been fixed and has been deployed. No more fun for you (well... at least until 30 days pass since your last name change).

Comment: _changing name before it went live_ oops it is already live

Comment: Too late. It is already live.