# How was my username changed without any notice or my permission?

Tags: support, user-accounts, display-names

My username was changed without any notice or my permission. How did it happen? I do understand that the username "idiotretard" is unorthodox but why has anyone changed it into something even offensive and humiliating, "iamuncreative"? I want it changed back!

Comment: Breathe, people.  Perhaps the name didn't jive with the rules of account names.

Comment: so? i dont want my username changed to something offensive and humiliating, and it shouldnt be

Comment: turn it off? press the caps lock button again

Comment: I don't see "iamuncreative" offensive, but rather funny in a self-deprecating way.  You obviously don't intend for that name to persist...so why not instead create a more traditional Internet handle?

Comment: what rules govern account names? where is it? i would be interested to see which rule does my name offend.

Comment: i dont like the traditional ones. wats there wrong with an unorthodox name?

Comment: I don't know who changed it, but there is a massive effort to purge use of the word "retard/retarded" as it is incredibly insulting to people with intellectual disabilities (see http://www.r-word.org/)

Comment: Do you really think the name "idiotretard" is appropriate on a professional site?

Comment: If you violate the terms of use (or offend a mod, both will do it), then the violation will be changed. If you managed to tick off a mod with your username, Then you will almost never like what it gets changed to, as seen here.

Comment: #7 in the [legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal) terms; Stack Exchange is free to remove a name at their discretion.  May be because of the word "retard", that's not a very positive name/word/handle.

Comment: [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99914/153691) might be helpful. Although I don't really see a canonical Q&A about appropriate user names.

Comment: right. thankyou for the @azulflame@Makoto@jonsca for the helpful comments. i understand why the name was changed now

Comment: @iamuncreative, a bug you probably don't know of. Directing a comment at multiple people does not work, only the first will get notified. I.e. Makato and jonsca did not recieve a notification that they got replies, only I did.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your name was flagged as offensive on Code Review and a moderator there changed it. Then it got synced to your other profiles.

Normally when a moderator edits a user in this way, they also send a message to let you know and explain that some names are inappropriate and so forth.

I'll follow up with the mod to see what happened with the message, but in the meantime I suggest you stick to usernames that are less likely to offend somebody.

Comment: right. thankyou for the clear info. how did you know a mod did it? and why did my user history(how do i check my userhistory anyway) show that i MYSELF made the change?

Comment: @iamuncreative Robert Harvey is only a mod on SO and meta SO. So he can't see events on other sites. On the other hand Anna Lear is a cross-site moderator and has access to info and histories of your account across the entire network.

Comment: @iamuncreative I know a mod did it because that's what your account history on Code Review tells me.

Comment: thankyou. i really is only annoyed at the name change. why do people vote it so down?

Comment: @iamuncreative My guess is that they disagree with your premise that "idiotretard" was a good name choice in the first place or that "iamuncreative" is *more* offensive.

Comment: what an unfriendly community (for this only. for all other stack exchange sites ive visited, i love the community)

Comment: wow. just looked at the questions on the site, at least a half have negative votes. my argument supported.

Comment: @namehere please read the FAQ before calling it "unfriendly." [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences), so you shouldn't take things so personally here. People have strong opinions and in general want the best for the site and for the community; they are not using their votes to make people feel good about themselves. And hopefully you realize now how unfriendly your previous username choice was.

Answer (score 14):

Well gee, maybe one of those words is offensive and not exactly politically correct. Perhaps a moderator, admin or dev happens to have a mentally challenged family member, or just has enough common sense to know that there are probably countless users on Stack Overflow who do. Would you call your boss that name, to his/her face? Would you feel good if your boss called you that name (to your face or behind your back)? If not, then it's probably not an appropriate username here, either.

Some interesting reading, if you care to:

[Possibly offensive usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117596/possibly-offensive-usernames)

[Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

[What are the rules governing display names and avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars)

[Policy on display names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37942/policy-on-display-names)

Comment: reading now....

Comment: <joke>I wouldn't call my boss Aaron Bertrand either. Therefore, it is not an appropriate username. logic!</joke>

Comment: `Would you call your boss that name?` I would not use that as criterion for deciding a username to use. `;)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno ok, whatever. How about would you be proud to tell your boss, or your spouse, or your mother, or your child that this is the username you chose?

Comment: That is a better criterion. Saying to use as username a word with which you would describe somebody else could have surprising results. If you hate a person, it's rather more probable you would not choose a nice nickname.

Comment: @kiamlaluno it had nothing to do with *hate*, it was more "if I call my boss <x>, will I keep my job?"

Comment: Even without hate, "Would you call anybody that way?" is less effective than "Would you like if somebody calls you that way?" I could call my boss Goofy (without telling her/him I do), but I would not like if somebody calls me Goofy.

Comment: @kiamlaluno so you think I meant what you call your boss under your breath or when they are not around? Why are you belaboring this? Did I really not make my point?

Comment: You didn't say which name. Why are you belaboring something that included `;)` at the end?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I've clarified, better?