# Why can I only change my Stack Overflow name once every 30 days?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, profile-page, display-names

I have a [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119919/kryton) on Stack Overflow. I recently decided to change the name on my profile. I did this, **but** I made a spelling mistake! I wrote "Kryton" instead of "Kryten"! When I tried to fix this, a message came back saying that I can only change my profile name every 30 days. Why? Is there any way I can fix my profile name?

Comment: Perhaps there should be a five or ten minute free-editing period like there is for comments.

Comment: @mmyers: How about we just get rid of the stupid rule that has no merit instead?

Comment: And the problems begin...

Comment: @mmyers - you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Email team@stackoverflow.com to correct this problem.

You might also attempt to change your profile on another site, and then copy the profile to stackoverflow on your user account page.  I don't know if this will work, but if it does please report back.

The change and discussion surrounding it is here:

[Can we restrict the ability of users to keep changing their names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names)

You might consider changing this to a "feature-request" and asking that a grace period of 5 minutes be allowed for typos and such when one does change their name.

Comment: It's probably better to flag a post for moderator attention.

Comment: attempt to copy profile is ending in http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/copy-profile (at least at the moment...)

Comment: I emailed team@stackoverflow.com and they cahnged the name for me. Thanks for all the answers everyone!

Answer (score 21):

There is now a 15 minute grace period after every displayname change during which displayname may be changed as often as you like.

Comment: @Fearless Leader: The guy keeps getting skewered for the perennial `status-bydesign`, and now you're complaining because he actually did something? ;)

Comment: @mmyers: I wouldn't be so sure about that! Jarrod and Geoff do the real work. ;) `</joke>` I didn't get a leadership haiku btw, it was a spam haiku.

Comment: @Fearless Spammer: It was a reference to *Rocky and Bullwinkle:* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fearless_Leader.

Comment: @mmyers: Oh, thanks for pointing out. Didn't know color TV existed back in 1959-1964!!!

Comment: Does the timer reset every time you change your display name? If so then you could just keep changing it, as long as you continually change it within 15 minutes.

Comment: @Brad: Is that a big problem? Sure, it's scriptable, but I think such a user would find themselves quickly suspended once it was pointed out. If I realize I made a typo at 14:59, should I be forced to live with my next typo? *\*changes name to Fat-fingered Bob\**

Comment: @Roger I was just pointing out a possible problem.

Comment: @Gnome,  It's as small a problem as the problem the team is trying to solve with this 30day cooldown feature.

Answer (score 6):

> [after a two-day grace period for new users, one display name change allowed every 30 days.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29196/should-you-be-allowed-to-change-your-handle-in-so/29257#29257)

[The owner ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

Go to that question and explain your problem. Some of us are hoping that he sees some of the problem arisen from this.

Comment: Yet the chances of this being changed are incredibly slim.