# What happens if I misspell my display name?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I only change my Stackoverflow Profile once every 30 days?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/why-can-i-only-change-my-stackoverflow-profile-once-every-30-days)

Just randomly noticed that users are not allowed to change their “display name” in the profile more than once in 30 days.

Surely this opens the possibility that someone accidentally typoes it and is then stuck with the misspelling for 30 days?

I’m not currently affected by this, but I just wonder what provisions there are to mitigate this problem.

Comment: you can circumvent this by having associated accounts...

Answer (score 1):

> [There is now a 15 minute grace period after every displayname change during which displayname may be changed as often as you like.
>   -- Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/why-can-i-only-change-my-stackoverflow-profile-once-every-30-days/38407#38407)

Answer (score 0):

You could ask a Moderator to change it for you but does it really matter?

It's only a display name and it's only for 30 days.