# Why am I not allowed to change my display name on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I only change my Stack Overflow profile once every 30 days?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/why-can-i-only-change-my-stack-overflow-profile-once-every-30-days)

I am not allowed to change my display name on Stack Overflow. When I try, the system says I must wait for 30 days to change my name.
Is it a site rule, or just matter of reputation that I have earned 'til now? If it is up to reputation, then what is the minimum reputation that I must earn before being able to change my display name?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with your rep.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/why-can-i-only-change-my-stackoverflow-profile-once-every-30-days