# Change Stack Overflow name

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change my name on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-in-stackoverflow)

I was assigned a pretty stupid name at Stack Overflow. How do I change it or how do I notify someone who could change it for me?

Comment: Ehm... You were assigned the name anopheles? How?

Comment: Ask the person who assigned you that name to assign you a new one. It usually works…

Answer (score 1):

There is an edit link in the upper right on your profile page.
For your account it is located here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1509533
Here you can edit the display name for your account.

Answer (score 0):

Click your name on the gray bar on top to go to your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509533/user1509533).
Then, click the edit link in the upper right.