# How can I change my username in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, profile-page, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change my name on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-stack-overflow)

I want to change my username. I logged in using Google and it didn't give me the chance of choosing one nickname.

How would I change my username?

Answer (score 4):

Click on your current nickname at the top of the page. Then, click "edit" towards the top right.

[image]

You will be able to edit your "Display Name".