# How do I see my posts with the changed layout?

Tags: support, user-accounts, top-bar, posts

When I log into Stack Overflow, my user ID (an arcane number you assigned me) is not at the top of the page. I used to click on it to see my posts. How do I review my questions and answers now?

Comment: Click on your reputation points.

Comment: [You can change that arcane number to something less arcane](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 17):

Click on your reputation counter in the top bar.

[image]

Comment: The fake orange bars made me laugh

Comment: Does it really take *that* long to visit SO?

Comment: @hichris123 Judging by all the "new topbar means I have to click **twice** to switch between meta and main" posts lately, I'd say yes.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName I want that link back too. :) Point taken.