# Is there a way to see what "Stack Exchange" sites you have NOT signed up for?

Tags: discussion

1. is there a way to tell which Stack Exchange sites you have "not" registered for?
2. Where would I ask questions about PC Software related questions and issues?
3. Is there a way to change the Username across ALL registered stack exchange sites?

Note: I use Google to register for new ones, and login.

Comment: Why would you **ever** need a list of all the sites you are not part of? If you want to join a site, join it.

Comment: second bullet: http://superuser.com?

Comment: @Oded - Completionist I guess, but perhaps your right.  Mostly so I can bounce around as needed asking questions, maybe even getting into some other subjects.

Comment: Third bullet; see the last screen shot here; http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216203/220332

Comment: The SE dropdown lists all the sites, as does http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no way (currently?) to see which sites you have not yet signed up to - you would have to do a manual comparison between the [all sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and [your own sites](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) (accounts tab).
2. [Super User](http://superuser.com) would probably be your best bet for general computing issues.
3. To change your username across all sites, edit your profile on one site and click on the "Save and Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" button at the bottom. Note that this will apply all profile fields to all of your accounts, not just your username.