# Editing my name

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I think SE should permit us to select different names for different websites. Also I can't seem to edit my name and status. Is there an option for editing these?

Comment: You can have different name on any different site, many people do it. When editing (on browser, not app) you can choose to save only for current site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard How can I edit?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-a-stack-exchange-site

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why can't I join SE overflow?

Comment: Because it's not a site, it's just the Stack Exchange portal. You can join only sites in the Stack Exchange network, e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), which you [joined already](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9397184/asif-iqubal), etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I couldn't edit from your given address.

Comment: Of course you can't. I didn't give link to directly edit your profile, I gave a link to question asking how to edit, with answers explaining how. If you can't understand the answers I'm sorry, I really can't do anything further to help you.