# what is recent Name on my stackoverflow profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

I can see the Recent Name on my profile page which shows 1.

I do not understand what this is.

Can you guys please let me know what this is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the number of name changes.

Click on the number to get:

[image]

It shows previous name [(within 90 days)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116870/one-of-my-names-is-missing/116960#116960) and the date they had been changed.

Note that you can only [change your name once each 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/why-can-i-only-change-my-stack-overflow-name-once-every-30-days).