# Tell me BEFORE I change my name that it has 30-day permanence

Tags: feature-request, display-names

Consider Meta Stack Exchange question *[Why can I only change my Stack Overflow name once every 30 days?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38289)*

I just went and changed my username on *Mi Yodeya* to Cnsersmoit (Scimonster scrambled). See comments: [Source for reciting all of T'hilim (Psalms)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/source-for-reciting-all-of-thilim-psalms/4889?noredirect=1#comment142342_4889) and https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19961013#19961013

However, I did so unaware that it would be stuck like that for the next 30 days. The moderators kindly offered to fix it for me, but I decided to leave it for now.

**But anyway, why wasn't I warned? Before clicking 'save', it should tell me that it'll be stuck.**

Comment: To punish people for doing silly things.