# How to change name in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, users, display-names

I have edited my profile at Stack Overflow many times. The edit form always reports as successful,  but my name at Stack Overflow is still [user905418](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905418/user905418) despite all my tries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the page [on your Super User profile](https://superuser.com/users/83890/paul?tab=accounts):

[Copy profile options http://phpcode.eu/images/1314569527.png](http://phpcode.eu/images/1314569527.png)

Click the first one. This would allow you to use on Stack Overflow the username used on Super User, if both the accounts are associated to each other.

Comment: tks, it's alright now :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you maybe tried to change your display name too often?

The [rule is that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29196/should-you-be-allowed-to-change-your-handle-in-so/29257#29257):

> after a two-day grace period for new users, one display name change allowed every 30 days.

Comment: If so, then as a workaround (if I recall correctly) Paul could still [copy his Super User profile](http://superuser.com/users/83890/paul?tab=accounts) (which seems okay) to other sites.